# HTML / CSS Comment Bubble arrow - suggestions on adjusting for border-line only

Tags: html, css

Just a quick one, second pair of eyes and what people think best approach would be on this... as your see on default bubble it has the arrow at the top however the second has transparent background but need to make the pointer on that one with a border outline as currently im using the fill using border width etc...

[image]

```css
/* bubble box */

.comment__arrow {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px 0 0 20px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #edf1ee;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
}

.comment__bubble {
  background: #edf1ee;
  padding: 24px 24px 0 24px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.comment__bubble--write {
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #EDF1EE;
  padding: 19px 24px 0 24px;
}

.comment__bubble--write .comment__arrow {
  border-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="comment__container comment__container--response">
  <p class="comment__arthor">John Thomas <span>Yesterday</span></p>
  <div class="comment__bubble">
    <span class="comment__arrow"></span>
    <p>I'm sorry to hear you didn't enjoy it Jimbo. It does need to be opened about an hour before drinking to give it some air and time to wam up to room tempeature.</p>
  </div>
  <p><a href="#" class="btn btn--secondary">Like</a> <span class="small">1 person likes this</span></p>

  <form id="comment_ID">
    <div class="comment__bubble comment__bubble--write">
      <span class="comment__arrow"></span>
      <textarea placeholder="Write a comment..." class="auto-expand" rows="1" data-min-rows="1"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit__coment_ID" class="pull-right btn btn--primary large" value="Send">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: so do you want to be transparent with a border?

Comment: yep for the second example, the first one and how i have the first one is right but want to apply a class (how i have done) to override to use a clear / border line version

Comment: I am not sure if you can do it that easy. 

but as an idea or a hack might be to do 2 triangles one with background grey that stay behind and other with a white background and 5% smaller

Comment: Why you cant do it. That is because the triangle itself is done from borders and there is basically no interior

Comment: Yea i know that, i mentioned that in question so my question was... as thats the cleanest and best way to do it but with this new requirements whats next best way to do it in other opinions.

Comment: Of course needs to be clean :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this code**

```css
    /* bubble box */

        .comment__arrow {
          border-style: solid;
          border-width: 20px 0 0 20px;
          border-color: transparent transparent transparent #edf1ee;
          position: absolute;
          top: -20px;
        }
    
        .comment__bubble {
          background: #fff;
          padding: 24px 24px 0 24px;
          margin-bottom: 12px;
          border-radius: 5px;
          position: relative;
              border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }
    
        .comment__bubble--write {
          background: transparent;
          border: 1px solid #EDF1EE;
          padding: 19px 24px 0 24px;
        }
    
        .comment__bubble--write .comment__arrow {
          border-color: transparent;
        }
    .comment__bubble.arrow:before {
margin-left: -20px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 20px 0 0 20px !important;
border-color: transparent transparent transparent #ccc !important;
    }
        .comment__bubble.arrow:after {
    margin-left: -19px;
        border-width: 18px 0 0 18px !important;
        border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff !important;
        }
        .comment__bubble.arrow:after, .comment__bubble.arrow:before {
            bottom: 100%;
            left: 10%;
            border: solid transparent;
            content: " ";
            height: 0;
            width: 0;
            position: absolute;
            pointer-events: none;
        }
```

```html
<div class="comment__container comment__container--response">
  <p class="comment__arthor">John Thomas <span>Yesterday</span></p>
  <div class="comment__bubble arrow">
    <p>I'm sorry to hear you didn't enjoy it Jimbo. It does need to be opened about an hour before drinking to give it some air and time to wam up to room tempeature.</p>
  </div>
  <p><a href="#" class="btn btn--secondary">Like</a> <span class="small">1 person likes this</span></p>

  <form id="comment_ID">
    <div class="comment__bubble comment__bubble--write">
      <span class="comment__arrow"></span>
      <textarea placeholder="Write a comment..." class="auto-expand" rows="1" data-min-rows="1"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit__coment_ID" class="pull-right btn btn--primary large" value="Send">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I managed to do anyway however want to mark your answer however why it the arrow thicker and not consistent with a 1px border line?

Comment: @James please see the updated code..now its 1px border line

Answer (score 1):

here you are I created an example how to colored border

```css
.triangle {
  width: 250px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333;
  font: bold .7em/180px Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.triangle:after,
.triangle:before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
}

.triangle:after {
  top: 5px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #FFF;
  border-width: 10px;
}

.triangle:before {
  top: 4px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #000;
  border-width: 11px;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle">
  css triangle with border color
</div>
```

Comment: I managed to do anyway however want to mark your answer however why is the arrow only showing half?